# How do I add sub tabs under Android SlidingTabLayout tabs?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-sliding

I have my sliding tabs working properly. However I need to another set of navigation tabs under each of the main tabs? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Study the code of pageviewer and related code in the activity and try to replace it suitably in each fragment

Comment: You might want to reconsider your applications navigation flow if you feel the need for nested tabs. Speaking from experience I can tell you that apps tend to be more complicated to navigate through when using nested tabs. You might want to consider using a Navigation Drawer to remove a layer of tabs.